# MVC3 DataAnnotationsExtensions error using numeric attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations, unobtrusive-javascript

I've installed Scott's Kirkland DataAnnotationsExtensions.

In my model I have:

```
[Numeric]
public double expectedcost { get; set; }
```

And in my View:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.expectedcost)
```

Now, when the page tries to render I get the following error:

> Validation type names in unobtrusive
>   client validation rules must be
>   unique. The following validation type
>   was seen more than once: number

Any ideas why I'm getting the error ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The quick answer is simply remove the attribute

```
[Numeric]
```

The longer explanation is that by design, validation already adds a *data-val-number* because it's of type *double*. By adding a *Numeric* you are duplicating the validation.

this works:

```
[Numeric]
public string expectedcost { get; set; }
```

because the variable is of type *string* and you are adding the *Numeric* attribute.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I basically had the same problem and I managed to solve it with the following piece of code: (As answered here: [ASP.NET MVC - "Validation type names must be unique."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203083/asp-net-mvc-validation-type-names-must-be-unique/32977829#32977829))

using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
And the ValidationRule:

public class RequiredIfValidationRule : ModelClientValidationRule
{
    private const string Chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

```
public RequiredIfValidationRule(string errorMessage, string reqVal,
    string otherProperties, string otherValues, int count)
{
    var c = "";
    if (count > 0)
    {
        var p = 0;
        while (count / Math.Pow(Chars.Length, p) > Chars.Length)
            p++;

        while (p > 0)
        {
            var i = (int)(count / Math.Pow(Chars.Length, p));
            c += Chars[Math.Max(i, 1) - 1];
            count = count - (int)(i * Math.Pow(Chars.Length, p));
            p--;
        }
        var ip = Math.Max(Math.Min((count) % Chars.Length, Chars.Length - 1), 0);
        c += Chars[ip];
    }

    ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
    // The following line is where i used the unique part of the name
    //   that was generated above.
    ValidationType = "requiredif"+c;
    ValidationParameters.Add("reqval", reqVal);
    ValidationParameters.Add("others", otherProperties);
    ValidationParameters.Add("values", otherValues);
}
```

}

I hope this helps.